# Send response to 2 webhooks via CURL

Tags: php, curl, zapier

We have a form on a website that currently uses Zapier Webhook to catch and push the information from the submitted form to our CRM.

How can I add another webhook to this form so when the form is submitted it hits both the endpoints?

Adding another step in the Zapier chain is not an option here.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t depend on your form to synchronise requests, instead send the request to your API and have it process the subsequent requests to relevant APIs as required.

Let the form only capture and send the data to your API and let the API process the steps after, this way you reduce issues happening on client sides, you have more control processing the data yourself on the API.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an option, we do not have access to the Zapier account this form hits or the associated accounts within Zapier. I know this is not good practice but I just need it to hit another endpoint. How would I add another cURL request?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an onSubmit function in JS? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

You can hook it up to the form much like the onClick function below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Webhook</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    function sendMessage() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "https://webhook");

      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

      var params = {
        thing: "value",
        thing2: "value2",
      }

      request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    }
  </script>
</html>
```